# Protractor Webdriver-manager update SSL error

Tags: ssl, webdriver, protractor

I am getting the following errors with `webdriver-manager update`. My protractor is at version `5.1.1`

> my_local_windows_directory>webdriver-manager update
>
> > events.js:160
> >     throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
> >           ^
>
> Error: write EPROTO 101057795:error:140770FC:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:unknown protocol:openssl\ssl\s23_clnt.c:794:
>
> > at exports._errnoException (util.js:1022:11)
> >     at WriteWrap.afterWrite (net.js:801:14)

Any ideas to resolve this issue. I am behind a corporate Lan, but I tried BYOD network as well, but still this did not resolve.

Answer (score 0):

1) Restart mac

2) Run **this ->** `webdriver-manager update`

3) Run **this ->** `webdriver-manager start`

4) Also you can check your ports `sudo lsof -iTCP -sTCP:LISTEN -n -P`