# Connection error with Protractor - Angular CLI

Tags: angular, protractor, angular-cli

I built an Angular 4 project using Angular CLI and am trying to run the default `Protractor` tests using the command `ng e2e`. When I run it, I initially get a successful compilation, but then after about 20 seconds, regardless of whether I do anything I get this error in my terminal:

> events.js:160 throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
>
> Error: connect ETIMEDOUT 172.217.10.80:443 at Object.exports._errnoException (util.js:1018:11)at exports._exceptionWithHostPort (util.js:1041:20) at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1086:14)

In my Chrome console I get this error:

> zone.js:2616 GET http://localhost:49155/sockjs-node/info?t=1501623806543 net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

I don't have any of these issue with my "regular" project on port 4200.

Comment: Check this [events.js:160 throw er;](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43175732/protractor-webdriver-manager-update-ssl-error/46561334#46561334)

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to set environment variables in order to enable the download behind a corporate proxy:

```
 SET https_proxy=http://www-proxy.corporate.com:80 *
 SET http_proxy=http://www-proxy.corporate.com:80 *
```

Also, this approach is more convenience if you need to specify credentials for your proxy, like this:

SET https_proxy=http://**yourUserName:yourPassword**@www-proxy.corporate.com:80

- Remember to replace http://www-proxy.corporate.com:80 with actual proxy value.
  This is a temporary fix as it may be cleared on the computer re-start. For a more permanent approach you can follow the instructions on this link:

[Can't run Angular > 2 e2e using protractor behind a proxy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49233422/cant-run-angular-2-e2e-using-protractor-behind-a-proxy?rq=1)

Answer (score 0):

@ecain,

When you do `ng e2e` it runs the `webdriver-manager update` command and it download webdriver dependency from network. In your case it was blocked on network.
You can try to set proxy in protractor.conf.js as below:

```
capabilities: {
'browserName': 'chrome',
'proxy': {
'proxyType': 'manual',
'httpProxy': 'http://proxy.abc.com:8080'}
```

If it will work in your case you can see output like below when run `ng e2e` on console

```
webpack: Compiled successfully.
[19:46:41] I/update - chromedriver: unzipping chromedriver_2.33.zip
[19:46:41] I/launcher - Running 1 instances of WebDriver
[19:46:41] I/direct - Using ChromeDriver directly...

DevTools listening on ws://127.0.0.1:12629/devtools/browser/01b4e971-94f1-
484a-87bc-ec9f41f30959
Jasmine started
```

If above solution does not work then set the proxy in system environment variable with key `http_proxy` and remove proxy inside from `npm` if it is set globally.Command to delete the proxy inside `npm` is: `npm config delete proxy`