# Can't run Angular > 2 e2e using protractor behind a proxy

Tags: angular, proxy, protractor, angular-e2e

will appreciate any help!

- I'm running on windows
- I installed protractor Version 5.3.0 globally
- Before updating webdriver I ran: `webdriver-manager clean`
- And updated version as follows:

> webdriver-manager update --ie32 --proxy
>   http://my-proxy:8080 --ignore_ssl

- node version 9.2.1
- npm version 5.7.1
- started dev server before starting e2e..

my protractor.conf file is as follows:

```
     const { SpecReporter } = require('jasmine-spec-reporter');

    exports.config = {
      allScriptsTimeout: 11000,
      specs: [
        './e2e/**/*.e2e-spec.ts'
      ],
        capabilities: {
    'browserName': 'chrome',
    'proxyType': 'manual',
    'httpProxy': 'http://my-proxy:8080'
  },
      directConnect: true,
      baseUrl: 'http://localhost:4200/',
      framework: 'jasmine',
      jasmineNodeOpts: {
        showColors: true,
        defaultTimeoutInterval: 30000,
        print: function() {}
      },
      beforeLaunch: function() {
        require('ts-node').register({
          project: 'e2e/tsconfig.e2e.json'
        });
      },
      onPrepare() {
        jasmine.getEnv().addReporter(new SpecReporter({ spec: { displayStacktrace: true } }));
      }
    };
```

Tried to ran tests first by: `ng e2e`
second by:

```
ng e2e --config ./protractor.conf.js --specs ./e2e\app.e2e-spec.ts
```

And still getting this proxy error:

```
events.js:136
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

    Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com:443
        at errnoException (dns.js:55:10)
        at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.onlookup [as oncomplete] (dns.js:97:26)
```

Comment: If the web app underlying test run on local, why need to set proxy.

Comment: I just assumed I need due to the error (contains 443 ssl port) + I had to use the proxy for updating the driver as I mentioned and that did work but running the e2e with: chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com:443, eventually it won't work for me with or without the proxy, I even tried to explicitly point on a selenium driver and added a selenium server  but that didn't went well.. not sure how to attack, can you suggest any other configuration?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`ng e2e` will execute `webdriver-manager start/update` in background, and `webdriver-manager start` will access "chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com" to query latest webdriver binary, your error comes from here.

Because `ng e2e` can't accept proxy from cli or pre-configured file, the only way you can set proxy for `webdriver-manager start/update` triggered by `ng e2e` is by `Environment Variable`.

Add below 3 Environment Variables:

```
HTTP_PROXY = http://my-proxy:port
HTTPS_PROXY = http://my-proxy:port
NO_PROXY = localhost,127.0.0.1, .yourcompany.com
```

Try `ng e2e` in new cmd window (don't try in old cmd window)

FYI, once you add the 3 Environment Variables, you no need to pass `--proxy` in cli when execute `webdriver-manager start/update`.

Comment: Thanks for your awesome explanation - worked for me :)

Comment: Which is the file I have to add 3 Environment Variables in Angular?

Comment: Add the 3 Environment Variables to machine, not into any file on machine.

Comment: @Dilip Solanki It is in Control Panel > System and Security > System > Advanced system settings > Environment Variables. Add new to 'System variables'.
I tried and it worked.

Comment: @Minato Not working for me anymore, is there any new solution?

Answer (score 0):

After we add the 3 environment variables, it almost works (thanks a lot for providing that solution) but if the proxy does not trust the site:  https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/

then we get:

```
    Error: unable to get local issuer certificate
        at TLSSocket.onConnectSecure (_tls_wrap.js:1058:34)
        at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:198:13)
        at TLSSocket._finishInit (_tls_wrap.js:636:8)
```

so, we still need to figure out a way to pass "ignoreSSL = true" to "ng e2e" because ng command should pass it down as "webdriver-manager update --ignore_ssl"

1.(Only working solution currently) One way is to modify the file
protractor\node_modules\webdriver-manager\built\lib\cmds\opts.js
by updating the value of opts[exports.IGNORE_SSL]

```
    opts[exports.IGNORE_SSL] = new cli_1.Option(exports.IGNORE_SSL, 'Ignore SSL certificates', 'boolean', true);
```

2. May be we try another environment variable or some how pass this value via angular.json file but I could not figure that out yet
3. Some how pass the certificate used by the proxy to trust the external site when the protractor runs the following:

```
    curl -o.\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\webdriver-manager\selenium\chrome-response.xml https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/
```