# error while updating web-driver for protractor

Tags: node.js, installation, webdriver, protractor, webdriver-manager

I am trying to install and update the webdriver manager but getting the error as shown in [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yGGP6.png). Have tried all the solutions provided for similar questions. But still facing the same issue

Commands:

```
npm install protractor # successful
webdriver-manager update # error on this command
```

Till yesterday everything was working fine but all of sudden i started to get this error.

> C:\Users\ABA13\workspace\Automation>webdriver-manager update
>   events.js:160
>
> throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
>        ^
>
> Error: read ECONNRESET at exports._errnoException (util.js:1020:11) at TLSWrap.onread (net.js:568:26)

Please help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I have tried to re-install the whole setup also but still facing the same issue.

Comment: probably you have closed a console but some process still alive. Try to reload your machine and try again.

Comment: @Oleski:I have already tried. I am using in a corporate network. Can that be a reason?

Comment: Yes that might be the reason, if you are aware of proxy settings try to webdriver-manager update --proxy=<proxydetails>

Comment: Check this [events.js:160 throw er;](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43175732/protractor-webdriver-manager-update-ssl-error/46561334#46561334)

Answer (score 0):

try below commands:

- webdriver-manager clean
- webdriver-manager update
- webdriver-manager update --standalone --versions.standalone=3.8.0
- webdriver-manager start --versions.standalone=3.8.0