# Protractor Webdriver update error : tunneling socket could not be established, cause=read ECONNRESET

Tags: node.js, proxy, webdriver, protractor

Getting error while updating Webdriver in Protractor.

Tried with proxy setting:

```
npm config set proxy http:Proxy:port

npm config set http_proxy http:Proxy:port

npm config set https_proxy https:Proxy:port
```

System info:

> Protractor version:5.2.0
>
> npm version:3.10.10
>
> mvn version: 3.5.2

Error:

```
tunneling socket could not be established, cause=read ECONNRESET 

C:\Windows\System32>webdriver-manager update
 events.js:160
  throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
  ^

Error: tunneling socket could not be established, cause=read ECONNRESET
at ClientRequest.onError (C:\Users\a655086\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\
protractor\node_modules\tunnel-agent\index.js:177:17)
at ClientRequest.g (events.js:292:16)
at emitOne (events.js:96:13)
at ClientRequest.emit (events.js:188:7)
at TLSSocket.socketErrorListener (_http_client.js:310:9)
at emitOne (events.js:96:13)
at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:188:7)
at emitErrorNT (net.js:1277:8)
at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:80:11)
at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:104:9)

C:\Windows\System32>
```

Comment: Seems to be a duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43175732/protractor-webdriver-manager-update-ssl-error and of itself: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47263795/tunneling-socket-could-not-be-established-cause-read-econnreset

Comment: The issue got resolved by running cmd as administrator using below command                                                                                                   
                npm config set proxy false

               npm cache clean  

  
  then restarting cntlm services

  Webdriver-manager update

Comment: You were setting proxy although you were not behind one ?!

Comment: Previously it was working but suddenly got this issue. Proxy already set.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33162560/error-tunneling-socket-could-not-be-established-cause-connect-econnrefused-10). In your attempts mentioned in the OP, I don't see `://` after http. Also note that even for https-proxy the protocol is http and not https. If you are not behind any proxy, you need to unset them as mentioned in the [linked answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33162560/error-tunneling-socket-could-not-be-established-cause-connect-econnrefused-10)

```
npm config set proxy http://proxyhost:proxyport
npm config set https-proxy http://proxyhost:proxyport
```

Comment: Are you behind a proxy?

Answer (score 0):

The issue got resolved by running cmd as administrator using below command

```
    npm config set proxy false

    npm cache clean
```

then restarting cntlm services

```
 Webdriver-manager update
```